# Chrome search in page when Ctrl+F shortcut is hijacked

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When a website hijacks the Ctrl+F combination (like Slack does), how can I activate Chrome's search-in-page function? Is there a mouse equivalent to Ctrl+F?

I've seen ways to disable the site's capture of the shortcut, but what I want is to leave the site alone while also accessing the browser's own functionality.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you (I don't know slack app that you mention) but press the 3 horizontal lines in the upper right and choose find from there or you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to get the same functionality. Also you can use <kbd>F3</kbd> to get the find bar to pop down.

Comment: On Mac OS X, you can add a different shortcut by opening the Chrome menu and going to Services -> App Shortcuts.

Comment: Mac is removing the Function row so F3 is unavailable.  Also Alt+E just opens the triple dot dropdown, which leaves us back to square one.  Ctrl-F is the only option, and it can't be remapped.  next action is removal of the Control, Alt, Fn, and butterfly keys to replace with buy it now buttons.

Answer (score 24):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

(Explanation: pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> gets the focus off the page, and into the browser's menus, allowing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> work normally.  Another way to accomplish the same is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd>.)

*May the administrators of websites which choose to hijack the browser's search function be cursed with unexplainable, intermittent, non-reproducible, errors and episodes of degraded performance.*

Comment: Blizzard does this and it's foking annoying.  https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/hearthstone/t/mechathun-fun-and-very-interactive/1548/22

Comment: It's very strange as I have this happen on my laptop often, but seem to use the same apps as my desktop and it never does.  This fixes it though - I can switch between a ton of apps, but this fixes it? Strange.  Think it may be YouTube musics local client.

Comment: For me "alt then ctrl+f" did not work but "alt+e then f" did.

Comment: Screw Jeff Atwood for hijacking Ctrl+F in Discourse.  (... otherwise he seems like a decent human.)

Answer (score 2):

On one website that hijacked both <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> *and* <kbd>F3</kbd> (both normally popping up the browser search box), I was able to access the browser search functionality by either (but ymmv):

- navigating the menus via keyboard shortcuts, i.e., <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (as the other answer, but just pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> alone didn't work);
- or, simply pressing twice in rapid succession, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, and although the first was captured by the webpage, the second popped up the browser search box.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a sledgehammer-to-push-in-a-thumbtack-solution but [Vimium](https://vimium.github.io/) has find functionality it implements independently of Chrome's (perhaps in JS).

> <kbd>/</kbd>  :   Enter find mode

#### Example Usage

[image]